iOS unit test using XCode menu vs using "xcodebuild test" commandline
I am new to iOS programming.
I have a project that contains some tests. I can run these tests by selecting "Product" -> "Test" from XCode menu and they run well on a physical device. I can also run these tests using xcodebuild test -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -configuration Debug -sdk iphoneos -destination id=<MY_SIMULATOR_DEVICE_ID> from commandline.
However, if I swap the device id from the simulator device to my physical device, the tests appear to start, freeze for a few seconds, then crash with the following output in the terminal.
Testing started
2024-04-23 19:35:41.994 xcodebuild[36786:17267497] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 30.775 elapsed -- Testing started completed.
2024-04-23 19:35:41.994 xcodebuild[36786:17267497] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.000 sec, +0.000 sec -- start
2024-04-23 19:35:41.994 xcodebuild[36786:17267497] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 30.775 sec, +30.775 sec -- end

Test session results, code coverage, and logs:
    /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-eexstwzprjmpijhalzmikpiyqqud/Logs/Test/Test-Runner-2024.04.23_19-34-58--0300.xcresult

Testing failed:
    Runner (1662) encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted. (Underlying Error: Test crashed with signal segv before starting test execution.))

System information:

macOS Sonoma 14.4.1
XCode 15.3
iPhone 13 Pro running iOS 17.4.1

I am wondering what have I missed moving between the two approaches. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

So I have figured it out myself. It was actually a combination of various factors.
First, "In iOS 14+, debug mode Flutter apps can only be launched from Flutter tooling, IDEs with Flutter plugins or from XCode". I only found out about this restriction when I removed a line that was causing the launch crash, and a message showed up on my phone telling me this after the app launched. I have not seen any documentation mentioning this.
This means, to run directly on a device (e.g. from commandline not XCode), the Flutter app must be compiled in Release configuration.
Second, my app starts successfully but couldn't enter any text for the automated testing. This was exactly why I was trying to run the app in Debug mode in the first place. I ran across this issue tracker and followed the recommendation of adding tester.testTextInput.register(); to my test code, and IT WORKED!
Now I can run the tests in release mode, directly on a physical device from command-line. This will definitely make CI easier!
